# Manytomanyfields issue : Fetch the columns where the manytomanyfield is applied

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, manytomanyfield

(Sorry for the inappropriate title. I am very bad at english. So I couldn't find out what should be the title)

I have 2 tables Devices and groups

```
class Devices(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device_name =\
        models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class Groups(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(Devices, blank=True)
```

I have more than 100000 devices and 100 groups. The devices can have multiple groups. I want to fetch the group_ids each device is having. I tried to loop through all the devices and fetch the group column. But it is taking too much time. Is there any pythonic way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `ManyToManyField` creates one intermediate model to save the relation. You can easily access to this model and filter the appropriate data.

This model have three fields:

- A `id` autonumeric field.
- Another id field for the model who has the `ManyToManyField`. Its name is `<<Name of the model in lower case>>_id`: `groups_id` now.
- Another id field apointing to he model in the `ManyToManyField`. The name convention is the same. `devices_id` in this case.

Now, with the access to the related model, you can query it like a normal Django model.

```py
class Devices(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    def get_group_ids(self):
        return Groups.get_ids_by_device(self)

class Groups(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(Devices, blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_ids_by_device(cls, device):
        relation = cls.devices.through
        qs = relation.objects\
            .filter(devices_id=device.pk)\
            .values_list('groups_id', flat=True)
        return list(qs)
```

To simplify the code, you can access the intermediate model through the `related_name` attribute.

```py
class Devices(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    def get_group_ids(self):
        relation = self.groups.through
        qs = relation.objects\
            .filter(devices_id=self.pk)\
            .values_list('groups_id', flat=True)
        return list(qs)

class Groups(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(Devices, blank=True, related_name="groups")
```

**EDIT:**

The previous is the most SQL efficient mode. Obviously you can use a more simple approach:

```py
device = Devices.objects.first()


device.groups.all()
# <QuerySet [groups for this device]>

device.groups.values_list('group_id', flat=True)
# <QuerySet [ids of the groups for this device]>
```

**Helpful Links:**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through